# How to use mapped types to map a subset of properties in a nested generic type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have a type like so:

```
type Thing = {
  name: string;
  deliveryDate: string;
  stuff: {
    place: string;
    datedContacted: string;
  }
}
```

That I want to create a mapped type with the same structure out of like so:

```
type FormThing = {
  name: string;
  deliveryDate: Moment;
  stuff: {
    place: string;
    datedContacted: Moment;
  }
}
```

I'm looking at TypeScript's "Mapped Types" here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html, but their examples seem to mostly go over how to convert all the properties of a type to another, not a subset.

I've tried to create a generic typing like so:

```
type DateFields = {
  deliveryDate: string;
  dateContacted: string;
}

export type Form<T> = T & {
  [Property in keyof DateFields]: Moment;
};
```

But it just doesn't seem to work as expected. Ideally I make it generic, so I can create a typed method that could handle the conversion of any sublevel of this nested object independently from `T` to `Form<T>`.

Comment: You are making it bit too complex in my view, you can simplify things and use type straightforward instead of trying to map the types. Because even if you are able to achieve this, the result has to be passed to function, which would then get more complext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this deep mapped type by first changing `DateFields` to union of string literals, and then by creating a recursive mapped type

```js
type Thing = {
    name: string;
    deliveryDate: string;
    stuff: {
        place: string;
        dateContacted: string;
    }
}

type DateFields = 'deliveryDate' | 'dateContacted';


type Form<T, Fields> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends Fields ? Moment : T[K] extends object ? Form<T[K], Fields> : T[K];
}
```

Inspect it in [this TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gWwgO2FAvFA3gXwFB6iRQAqAFgJbIDmG2eUjUyAhkgFxQDOwATldQDcDJgBMIAGwoA3CLxAARFsAice-GsKbdgAVwBm+zlhHbGYCSwDGqnRqGmzo5RADCcVNZWi1fAVqZ8fEJwaCUVADEKSVEuOgBycSlZeXCIeKgAHyhEl3dPK2944QIiaAi4XgQAHhIAGigomK4APjoTbQBtAGkoKigAawgQOH1SAF1OXogADxVkWMboiUWAflhEFDROEh7xqFn5xbgAIwArCEKodYqq2r2GppXWqB294WCy2BYwSFFyAR0W41AE0BppJ6xFoEcRWSy8aBWDw8KAIH5-UHUTgwdEQf6UTRAA)